# How to retrieve statistical SQL results with PHP?

Tags: php, sql, statistics

After hours of trying and searching the net, I'm giving up and am asking for your help. How to retrieve statistical SQL results with PHP? I created a test table with five entries, with primarily numeric values. With phpMyAdmin I can do several statistical computations, but with PHP I cannot even get a sum.

In SQL language that is extremely simple:

```
SELECT SUM(`Arbeidspercentage`) FROM `enq_vs`;
```

I put that in a PHP file together with another function, like this:

```
<?php
  require "connect.php";
  $kwearie_1 = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM `enq_vs`");
  $x = "Arbeidspercentage";
  $y = "Verzoeken_alg_toegek";
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($kwearie_1))
    {
    echo $row[$x] . " " . $row[$y] . '<br>';
    };

  $kwearie_2 = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT SUM(`Arbeidspercentage`) FROM `enq_vs`");
  $kwearie_2_readable = mysqli_fetch_all($kwearie_2);
  echo $kwearie_2_readable;
  mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

But all I'm getting is results of the first kwearie. The second one gives either nothing, the word 'Array', or an error report that matters cannot be converted to a string. I've tried all sub functions, from 'fetch_all' to 'fetch_row'.

How is this done? A good tutorial will do, too.

Comment: For dumping, use `var_dump()` instead of `echo`. It is always good practice to alias a generated column in select. F.ex: `... SUM(Arbeidspercentage) as sum_value ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think aliases will perfectly fit here:

```
SELECT SUM(`Arbeidspercentage)` as 'sum_arbeid' ...
...
echo $row['sum_arbeid'];
```

Comment: The simplest method also produced the best result. Thanks! :-)

Answer (score 0):

You have to itterate through the result. See http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php - fetch_all and fetch_assoc are replacable. But you should consider using assoc for not generating data you don't need in your output.

Answer (score 0):

When you do mysql_fetch_all, you get an array as a result.  You can not simply echo out the results of an array.  Use a foreach loop instead.

```
$kwearie_2_readable = mysqli_fetch_all($kwearie_2);
foreach ($kwearie_2_readable as $row) {
    // $row is an array as well.  
    var_dump($row);
}
```

In this case you know that your result will only have one row so you could also do:

```
var_dump($kwearie_2_readable[0]);
```

Ultimately you want to echo the specific element you're interested in:

```
echo $kwearie_2_readable[0][0];
```

Comment: Although the result your method produced did contain the sum, it was in a form that could not be used in further functions: `array(1) { [0]=> string(3) "322" }`. Still, thank you for jumping in. This is one awesome forum when it comes to timely replies! :-)

Comment: No problem.  Yes SO is a great forum.  Based on your feedback, you probably could have done echo $kwearie_2_readable[0][0];  Still I would urge you to read up a bit on php arrays and how they work.  They support both numeric indexes and associative indexes (string keys) even in the same array.  The mysql fetching routines allow you to return one or the other or both when you fetch a row, depending on the specific fetch_* method you use.  The SQL alias is always a good way to guarantee a column name on computed columns, but that is not a php specific technique, albeit helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding MYSQLI_ASSOC as a second parameter to mysqli_fetch_array call. It will force the function to return assoc array instead of integer indexed one. Same goes with the mysqli_fetch_all call. These calls will always return an array so echo will always print Array. Try var_dump instead of echo.

```
var_dump($kwearie_2_readable);
```